# Como pasar datos de un objecto al aplication.properties

Tags: spring-boot

Cordial saludo.

Actualmente tengo mi `aplication.properties` de la siguiente manera:

```
spring.mail.host= smtp.gmail.com

spring.mail.username=correo@gmail.com

spring.mail.password=123

spring.mail.port=587

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Pero necesito no pasarle los datos quemados si no desde un objecto con sus respectivos datos guardados en la base de datos les agradezco cualquier clase de ayuda mil gracias.

Comment: Podrias porfavor dar mas contexto a tu pregunta? ejemplo: Como pasar los atributos de un objeto al application.properties? en tu decription no entiendo por quemado..

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un .properties así:

```
email=test@test.com
```

Debes crear una clase la cual tenga la anotación @Component como este ejemplo;

```
   @Component
   @PropertySource("classpath:global.properties")
   public class GlobalProperties {

        @Value("${email}")
        private String email;    
       //getters and setters
   }
```

De tal manera que la invocas  por medio del encapsulamiento y le setteas  el valor de la base de datos  que previamente tienes almacenada en algún lugar espero te ayude